# Android: OptionalDataException upon ObjectInputStream.readObject()

Tags: android, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream, optionaldataexception

**Situation** : From my Android server, I'm sending a simple String OBJECT to the client. I use ObjectOutputStream at the server, and ObjectInputStream at the client.

Server code:

```
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.reset();

            Object myStr = new String(res); //res is some String
            mOutput.writeObject(myStr);
            mOutput.flush();
```

Client Code:

```
            Log.v("CLIENT","Attempting to receive results from Server");

            obj = objectInputStream.readObject(); //ERROR THROWN HERE

            Log.v("CLIENT", "Object received");

            res = (String)obj;
```

**Problem** : At the client end, I get an OptionalDataException during readObject(). The interesting thing is, that its able to read it properly only for the first time, but subsequently throws this exception.

As you can see, I flush() and reset() the OutPutStream before and after sending the object. Why does this error still occur ?

Comment: Edited my code. I tried sending a String Object, a pure Object with a String inside it, but the same error occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. Android's documentation says that there should be no leftover primitives in the `ObjectOutputStream` when sending objects.

It turns out I was also writing a byte (using `writeBytes()`) after sending the object. The `flush()` and `reset()` did not remove this stray byte in the `ObjectOutputStream`, and hence the `ObjectInputStream` reported an `OptionalDataException`.

Make sure you also remove any stray `ObjectOutputStream.writeInt()`, `writeBoolean(), writeUTF()` or `writeChars()` or whatever before you read the `ObjectInputStream` ...Otherwise this exception will be thrown !

Wonder why the prior and immediate `flush()` and `reset()` did not work ?

Comment: You don't have to remove them. You just have to make sure you actually read them. Otherwise what exactly was the point of writing them in the first place? There is exactly no reason why `flush()` or `reset()` should, or even could, take care of this for you.